# Understanding the proof if the given function is Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, epsilon-delta, riemann-integration

I am trying to understand the proof if the function given in the picture below is integrable by using the Epsilon-Delta definition of Reimann integral. I was supposed to take real analysis course this semester but didn't. So I am self studying and I was going through Reimann integrals. As far as i understand, for any tagged partition P of [0,3], i split it into two disjoint partitions P_1 and P_2 where P_1 forms a partition of [0,1] having its tag within and similarly for P_2 having tags only in (1,3]. Now i understand that the subintervals in P_1 not necessarily are the same subintervals  formed in P. But in the proof it seems like the subintervals are the same.
By saying P_1 has its tags in [0,1], does it mean its a partition of [0,1] and not [0,3]? If someone can clear my misunderstandings or provide me with an explanation of this proof, I'd be grateful.
[image]

Comment: Splitting the domain avoids a nuisance of handling an interval containing $x=1$.

Comment: Can you let us know the book from which the proof is taken?

Comment: $\dot{\mathcal P}_1, \dot{\mathcal P}_2$ are not partitions of $[0,1]$ and $[1,3]$. Rather we have taken an arbitrary partition $\dot{\mathcal P}$ of $[0,3]$ and $\dot{\mathcal P}_1$ contains the subintervals of $\dot{\mathcal P}$ whose tags lie in $[0,1]$ and $\dot{\mathcal P}_2$ contains subintervals of $\dot{\mathcal P}$ whose tags are in $(1,3]$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The proof was taken from Introduction to real analysis 3th edition by Robert G. Bartle and Donald R. Sherbert. In the forth edition, the proof is abit different.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh but  why aren't they partitions? considering delta is VERY small, it seems just right to say '\dot{\ mathcal P}_1' is actually the interval [0,1] ,doesn't it? or it will just be too close to 1 but never 1?

Comment: That will be the case only when the right end point of last interval of $\dot{\mathcal P} _1$ is $1$. And if $a$ is near $b$ then it doesn't necessarily mean that $a=b$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh So the last  subinterval of P1 might be less than 1 or 1 but not exceeding 1? right ?

Comment: Well the last subinterval can exceed $1$ but it remains less than $1+\delta$.

Comment: This is what the author says. The partition $\dot{\mathcal P} _1$ contains $[0,1-\delta]$ and is contained in $[0,1+\delta]$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124912/discussion-between-mulaan22-and-paramanand-singh).

Answer (score 2):

IF you took *arbitary* other partitions $\dot{\mathcal P}_1, \dot{\mathcal P}_2$, then you would be right that the subintervals and tags may not be the same as in $\dot{\mathcal P}$.

But that is not what they are doing. It is not their purpose here to investigate the integrals on $[0,1]$ or $[1,3]$, so they do not need arbitrary partitions. The point of $\dot{\mathcal P}_1$ and $\dot{\mathcal P}_2$ is to produce an estimate of $S(g;\dot{\mathcal P})$. They *define* $\dot{\mathcal P}_1$ to be the *subintervals of $\dot{\mathcal P}$* with tags in $[0,1]$, and $\dot{\mathcal P}_2$ to be the remaining *subintervals of $\dot{\mathcal P}$*. The result is $\dot{\mathcal P} = \dot{\mathcal P}_1 \cup \dot{\mathcal P}_2$. The partition intervals are those of $\dot{\mathcal P}$ by definition.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to understand the argument given by author without going into too much symbolism.

We are given a partition $\dot{\mathcal P} $ of $[0,3]$ with norm less than $\delta$. This means that we are given a set of sub-intervals $$[x_0,x_1],[x_1,x_2],\dots,[x_{n-1},x_n]$$ where $$0=x_0<x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n=3$$ We are also given some tags $t_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$. And further for each $i$ we have $x_i-x_{i-1}<\delta$.

This also implies that $$t_1\leq t_2\leq \dots\leq t_n$$ The key step in the argument is to separate the  tags $t_i$ which lie in $[0,1]$ from those which lie in $(1,3]$. To make the argument explicit there exists a unique integer $k$ with $1\leq k\leq n$ such that $t_1,t_2,\dots,t_k$ all lie in $[0,1]$ and $t_{k+1},t_{k+2},\dots,t_n$ lie in $(1,3]$ (this part may be non existent if $k=n$).

Now all the sub-intervals $$[x_0,x_1],[x_1,x_2],\dots, [x_{k-1},x_k]$$ make up $\dot{\mathcal P} _1$ and $$[x_k, x_{k+1}],[x_{k+1},x_{k+2}],\dots,[x_{n-1},x_n]$$ make up $\dot {\mathcal P} _2$ (which may be empty as remarked earlier).

Now we can note that $$x_k - t_k\leq x_k-x_{k-1}<\delta$$ so that $$x_k<t_k+\delta\leq 1+\delta$$ Further note that $$t_{k+1}-x_{k}\leq x_{k+1}-x_k<\delta$$ so that $$x_k>t_{k+1}-\delta>1-\delta$$ It thus follows that the union of sub-intervals in $\dot {\mathcal P} _1$ contains $[0,1-\delta]$ properly and is properly contained in $[0,1+\delta]$.

A similar analysis can be done for $\dot{\mathcal P} _2$.